# jQuery to pass href to soundManager

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass a unique url to play the different songs. If I run an `alert()` it displays the unique href of the span tag but when I try `url = $(this).attr('href');` in the playSound function it doesn't work?

## HTML PAGE

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/mp3player.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscroller.js"></script>
<script src="js/soundmanager2-jsmin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mp3player.js"></script>

<head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="player">
<img src="images/background.png"/>
<img src="images/play_button.png" id="play_btn"/>
<img src="images/pause_button.png" id="pause_btn"/>
<img src="images/stop_button.png" id="stop_btn"/>
<img src="images/fwd_button.png" id="fwd_btn"/>
<img src="images/back_button.png" id="back_btn"/>
<img src="images/vb10.png" id="volumebar"/>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div id="time"></div>
<div id="scroller_container">
 <div id="scroller">
  <p></p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <span class="Play" href="../sounds/5.mp3"><img src="images/play_button.png"/></span>

        <span class="Play" href="../sounds/4.mp3"><img src="images/play_button.png"/></span>

        <span class="Play" href="../sounds/3.mp3"><img src="images/play_button.png"/></span>


        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

## MP3Player.js #

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   soundManager.url = 'swf';
   soundManager.flashVersion = 8; 
   var theMP3;
   var currentSong =0;
        soundManager.onready(function() {
            function playSound(){
                theMP3= soundManager.createSound({
                     id:'sound'+currentSong,
                     url: href
                                    });
             theMP3.play();
            };

        $(".Play").click(function(){                
                var href = $(this).attr('href');                
                playSound();

            });         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urll=''
   soundManager.url = 'swf';
   soundManager.flashVersion = 8; 
   var theMP3;
   var currentSong =0;
        soundManager.onready(function() {
            function playSound(){
                theMP3= soundManager.createSound({
                     id:'sound'+currentSong,
                     url: urll
                                    });
             theMP3.play();
            };

        $(".Play").click(function(){                
                urll = $(this).attr('href');                
                playSound();

            });         
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var urll = ''
    soundManager.url = 'swf';
    soundManager.flashVersion = 8;
    var theMP3;
    var currentSong = 0;
    soundManager.onready(function () {
        function playSound(str) {
            theMP3 = soundManager.createSound({
                id: 'sound' + currentSong,
                url: str
            });
            theMP3.play();
        };

        $(".Play").click(function () {
            urll = $(this).attr('href');
            playSound(urll);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks,It kinda works but after I click on a button, all 3 buttons will play the same sound (the first button clicked sound)